# how to Update and append value in Labels for kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have requirement, where I would like to update and append labels value on deployment, using some form of automation

For example on initial Deployment I have set label on kubernetes deployment as

```
labels:
    customer: customerA
```

Now I would like update label as,

```
labels:
    customer: customerA,CustomerB
```

One of the way I figured out to achieve this is via using kubectl patch command

```
 kubectl patch deployment application --patch '{"spec": {"template": {"metadata": {"labels": {"customer": "customerB"}}}}}'
```

However above command shows the obvious behaviour and overwrites the previous label for customer and set the new value as

```
labels
    customer: CustomerB
```

however I would like to append the value in lables customer, one of of the way is to use command as below

```
kubectl patch deployment application --patch '{"spec": {"template": {"metadata": {"labels": {"customer": "customerA,customerB"}}}}}'
```

however with above approach, I would need to maintain list of customer label value and pass it.

is there a way to append values of labels in existing deployment, so that I dont need to maintain the list.

Comment: you can use kubectl label deployment

Comment: I dont want to update metadad.labels, i wanted to update spec.template.metadata.labels

Comment: sorry I think it's better that you start to take look in helm chart

Comment: updating  spec.template.metadata.labels means labeling the replicaSet, you can use `kubectl label replicaSet $RS_NAME`

Comment: Maybe juste use `kubectl edit deployment <NAME>` ? Then you can change the labels in any way you want.

Comment: Agree with @c4f4t0r, I would look around helm chart.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK K8s labels doesn't accept comma separated values -> [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/_print/#syntax-and-character-set).
Regex used for validation is `'(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')`.

But you can always try some workarounds:

```
# Get the current values (requires jq)
CURRENT=$(kubectl get deploy application -o jsonpath='{.metadata.labels}' | jq .customer -r)

# Merge then apply
kubectl label deploy application customer=${CURRENT}.Customer-C --overwrite

# Check
kubectl get deploy application -o jsonpath='{.metadata.labels}' | jq .customer -r
```